# How to show two different activity in recent task from same application in android?

Tags: android

I want to open an activity from widget and another activity from application launcher. Both the activity should show in recent task at once. Currently the current activity override the previous opened activity. I want both activity in recent task.

Please find the codes here:

```
public class SimpleAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for(int i=0; i<appWidgetIds.length; i++){
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,intent, 0);
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.activity_main);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnClick, pending);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId,views);
            Toast.makeText(context, "widget added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="hcl.mobility.testwidget">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestWidget">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" />

        <receiver android:name="hcl.mobility.testwidget.SimpleAppWidget">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/simple_app_widget_info" />
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

```
<appwidget-provider
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="146dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
    android:minHeight="146dp"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/activity_main">
</appwidget-provider>
```

[app launcher activity in recent task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ms3a3.jpg)

[widget activity in recent task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0Fob.jpg)

I want to show both activity in recent task.

Comment: try by setting launch mode for activity as SingleInstance

Comment: Can you provide a code example to show what you have already done and what you are attempting to do? This will make it easier for others to provide assistance. With the minimal detail that you have provided, those that might help you can only guess at solutions that will solve your issue.

Comment: @KishanMaurya I use singleInstance still showing only one activity in task

Comment: @JasonK. I added the code in my question. Please look into this. Thanks

Comment: <activity android:name=". SecondActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:taskAffinity="com.example.stackoverflowhelper1"/>

Answer (score 0):

delete `android:launchMode="singleTask"`

addFlags

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
```